# Can I cache my header file?

Tags: php, html, browser-cache

My header.php file gets included in all my scripts and includes a toolbar based on twitters bootstrap style sheet.  Every time a page loads it flashes as the page loads. I assumed the header was getting cached by default but it doesn't appear to be.  Is there a way to force it to use cache?

The head section of the file looks like this:

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<title><?php echo($title); ?></title>
<?php if (isset($meta)) {echo($meta);} ?>

<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />  

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
/* Override some defaults */  
<?php if (isset($extra_styles)) {echo($extra_styles);} ?>


</style>

</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of caching:

**Client caching**
If you mean client caching, then no. Clients cache individual contents like images and HTML files, but not part of them. There is no fancy HTML tag or similar to tell the browser which special part to cache.

**Server caching**
Server caching mean the server keeps some frequently accessed content in RAM to reduce I/O and save processing time. You can always cache your HTML header section in the RAM. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you expect to get cached? The browser can't cache a subset of the HTML on one page, for use in subsequent pages; it just doesn't work like that.  The browser caches *files* as a whole, whether they are PHP-generated HTML pages, Javascript source, or images.

It doesn't matter if your header is the same on all pages, because it is generated by the same  `include`'d PHP file - the browser knows nothing about what your webserver is doing with different PHP files before it is served. The browser just gets the page's HTML as a whole, and interprets it.

Comment: Basically just the toolbar at the head of the page